# API Changes for Google Drive’s folder structure and sharing models

Tags: google-drive-api

I used to use below Google Drive API to move my existing file to another drive folder

```
drive.files().update(fileId=cloudFile['id'],addParents=sharefile,media_body=media).execute()
```

I just got an email said that the Google Drive folder structure is changed and I'm not allowed to use "addParent" to share filers anymore. I was wondering how can I do this with drive API? I don't want to re-write the entire code, and I'm looking for the simplest way to replace addParents API.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Instead of giving a file multiple parents, you can create a shortcut to another Drive file instead (such as a folder).*

#### More Information:

You can use the shortcuts functionality of Google Drive instead of the multiple parents functionality to emulate the kind of behaviour. From the Documentation:

> Shortcuts are files that link to other files on Google Drive.

Shortcuts are Drive files with the `application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut` MIME type, that point to another file or folder on a Google Drive. You can read more about this [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts).

#### References:

- [Create a Shortcut to a Drive File](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts)
- [Find files & folders with Google Drive shortcuts](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9700156)
- [G Suite and Drive MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)